# Is there any way to ignore certain fields when using @ShouldMatchDataSet with NoSQLUnit?

Tags: java, mongodb, unit-testing, nosql

I'm using NoSQLUnit for testing with a Mongo database.

I want to insert new entities that include the current time as creation time and then use the @ShouldMatchDataSet function to check that they were properly created.

I know all the concrete values except the creation time, is there any way to use @ShouldMatchDataSet ignoring this concrete field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have contributed to NoSQLUnit with a custom comparison strategy named FlexibleComparisonStrategy that includes following changes. It's available since version 0.8.1 and to use it just add the next annotation to the class signature:

```
@CustomComparisonStrategy(comparisonStrategy = MongoFlexibleComparisonStrategy.class)

public class SomeTests {
```

Comparison strategy that checks that all the expected data exists in the Mongo database. It doesn't compare that all the data stored in the database is included in the expected file, so other data not defined in the expected resource could exist in Mongo. It just assure that the expected data exists.

Checks the following assertions:

- Checks that all the expected collections are present in Mongo DB, but accepts other collections stored in the database that are not defined in the expected file.
- Checks that all the expected objects are present in Mongo DB, but accepts other objects stored in the same collections that are not defined as expected.
- For each object checks that all properties set to be ignored its value exist in the object stored in the database, but it accepts any saved value.

The annotation **@IgnorePropertyValue(properties = {String...})** allows the user define the properties that should be ignored when checking the expected objects.

It accepts two formats for property definition:

1. **collection.property** : When are defined both collection and property name the exclusion will only affect to the indicated collection.

   - e.g: With *@IgnorePropertyValue(properties = {"book.date"})*, the property date *will* be ignored in each object of the *book* collection. If other objects in different collections have the property *date* it won't be ignored.
2. **property** : When only is defined the property name it will be excluded from all objects in any expected collection.

   - e.g: With *@IgnorePropertyValue(properties = {"date"})*, the property *date* will be ignored in each object, no matter the collection.

The values of the properties to be ignored should be named following the rules for valid collection and property names defined in [Mongo DB: naming restrictions](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#naming-restrictions) document.

When more than one object stored in the database matches the expected object after ignoring properties a warning is shown notifying the number of objects that were found.